# Android Auto : Error al lanzar el DHU en Mac

Tags: android, android-auto

He creado un proyecto de prueba en `Mac OSX 10.11.1` para [android-auto](/questions/tagged/android-auto), y siguiendo las instrucciones de la [guía](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/auto/start/index.html?utm_campaign=android-auto-315#test-it) estoy obteniendo el siguiente mensaje a la hora de lanzar el `DHU` (simulador de Android Auto):

> 015-12-04 08:46:41.717 desktop-head-unit[764:17863] 08:46:41.717 WARNING: 140: This application, or a library it uses, is using the deprecated Carbon Component Manager for hosting Audio Units. Support for this will be removed in a future release. Also, this makes the host incompatible with version 3 audio units. Please transition to the API's in AudioComponent.h. Connecting over ADB to localhost:5277...connected. Failed to read from transport - disconnect. Exiting...

¿Qué puedo hacer para solucionarlo?

Comment: usted tiene el modo desarrollador "developer mode" habilitado en su telefono. Por otro lado lo primero es una advertencia y quizas no sea la causa por la cual no funciona pues es la forma antigua en que se manejaba el sonido en ese OS.

Answer (score 4):

no había visto tu pregunta, actualmente estoy trabajando con TV y Auto en MAC como hobbie, te menciono que mi ejemplo también tuvo el mismo problema al usar la clase `AudioSystem`, resulta que es un problema que tiene [OpenAl-Soft](http://kcat.strangesoft.net/openal.html), el cual por el momento hasta diciembre 2015 no ha tenido solución:

**[OS X 10,11 Advertencia # 20](https://github.com/kcat/openal-soft/issues/20)**

De hecho acabo de encontrar en un foro que ya fue reportado **[aquí](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8138754)**.